# Create a platform independent path string

Tags: javascript, firefox, filesystems, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm using the Mozilla addon sdk for development and need to create a file on the local system.
Currently I use the statement below but feel it may not cover all platforms.
Running the statement on Windows 7 and Windows XP returns:

```
console.log(system.platform);
winnt
```

Running it on Linux returns:

```
console.log(system.platform);
linux
```

Is there a more reliable way to create the `fullPath` string, without having to check contents of `system.platform`?

```
pathToFile = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
    .getService(Ci.nsIProperties).get("Home", Ci.nsIFile).path;

if (system.platform.indexOf("win") == 0) {
    fileSeparator = "\";

}else{
    fileSeparator = "/";
}

fullPath=pathToFile + fileSeparator + 'myFile.txt'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a little modfication to your code should do the trick

```
var file = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/directory_service;1"]
                .getService(Ci.nsIProperties).get("Home", Ci.nsIFile);

file.append("myFile.txt");

var fullPath = file.path;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to point out an alternative to @Kashif's answer.

Use [`FileUtils.getFile()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/FileUtils.jsm#getFile%28%29), which is just a convenience function, essentially doing multiple `.append()`s, one per item in the parts array.

```
Cu.import("resource://gre/modules/FileUtils.jsm");
var file = FileUtils.getFile("Home", ["myFile.txt"]);
var path = file.path;
```

Answer (score 0):

The SDK has a ['fs/path'](https://github.com/mozilla/addon-sdk/blob/master/lib/sdk/fs/path.js) module that has parity with [Node's path API](http://nodejs.org/api/path.html)